# Click on the addsubview event button

Tags: ios

I have a button in a subview called `UIViewControllerB`. Someone who taught me how to capture click event in UIViewControllerB will add a new view to UIView in `UIViewcontroller` A under string as my code.

This is the button in `ViewControllerB` displayed in UIView in UIViewController A

```
@IBAction func button_complate(sender: AnyObject) {
NSLog("aaa", "bbb")
}
```

Here is the `UIViewControllerA` containing `UIView`

```
@IBOutlet weak var addview: UIView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: And your question is ...

Answer (score -1):

try code:

```
    class UIViewControllerA: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func addView(/*param    */) {
        // do something
    }

    // when push to UIViewControllerB set install for viewcontrollerA
    private func goToScreenB(){
        let viewB = UIViewControllerB()
        viewB.viewcontrollerA = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewB, animated: true)
    }
}


class UIViewControllerB: UIViewController {
//    In UIViewControllerB create a install of UIViewControllerA
    var viewcontrollerA : UIViewControllerA?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    @IBAction func button_complate(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.viewcontrollerA?.addView()
    }

}
```